# regex_match is failing to match string with special regex string

Tags: c++, regex

i am trying to use regex_match to match specific string from regex string received from json file

the following will return false

```
regex_match ("pciereg044", regex(".*(pciereg041|pciereg047|pciereg044).*") )
```

where the following regex return true

```
regex_match ("pciereg044", regex(".*(pciereg041|pciereg044).*") )
```

it seems like the extra |string , are effecting my matching,what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Your first example returns `true` for me. What compiler & version are you using?

Comment: c++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)

Comment: That is a very old version of the compiler. I *think* regex wasn't properly implemented before at least `GCC v4.9`. Can you upgrade the compiler?

Comment: Testing for this match is utterly trivial if you don’t use regular expressions. `std::string` can search for a matching substring and for a character match.

Comment: i donot think it will work if i have string like pciereg044ah , after all i need regex its only example .